# Display data in list view with sub Item from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have write a code to upload a audio file with its name and artist Name and its successfully uploaded. but when i have fetch the data from the firebase in the list view then it only shows the Name of Songs in list view but i want to display artist name also in sub item of list View 
My code 
Fetch Code.

```
ViewUploadsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//the listview
ListView listView;


//database reference to get uploads data
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

//list to store uploads data
List<Upload> uploadList;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_upload);

    uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    //adding a clicklistener on listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);


            try {

                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource(upload.getUrl());
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.stop();
                    player.release();

                } else {
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    });



    //getting the database reference
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //retrieving upload data from firebase database
 mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploadList.add(upload);
            }
            String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];
                           for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
                              }

                      //displaying it to list
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads);


            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}

   }
```

Upload File code

```
public class Upload {

public String name;
public String url;
public String ar;//artist

// Default constructor required for calls to
// DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
public Upload() {

}

public Upload(String name, String url,String ar) {
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
  this.ar=ar;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
      public String getAr ()
  {
   return ar;
  }
   }
```

Output What I upload

[image]

And What i get

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` your `.XML` file looks actually like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

This means that in your layout you have only one `TextView`. What i see from your screenshots you need to have two TextViews. So, you can also use:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

But this will be also a **`constraint`**. The best solution would be to use your own custom `ArrayAdapter`. For this, you first you need to create a `.XML` file for your item list named: `list_item.xml`. This file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your `CustomArrayAdapter` should look like this:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Upload> {
    CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Upload> arrayList) {
        super(context, 0, arrayList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View listItemView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView firstTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.first_text_view);
    TextView secondTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.second_text_view);

    Upload upload = getItem(position);
    if (upload != null) {
        firstTextView.setText(upload.getAr());
        secondTextView.setText(upload.getName());
    }
    return listItemView;
    }
}
```

To call the constructor of `CustomArrayAdapter` class you need to use this line of code:

```
CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, yourArrayList);
```

And then set the adapter to your `ListView` like this:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

With this code you are free to use as many views as you want.

Comment: Sir It is shows this Error   `Error:(104, 69) error: incompatible types: <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Activity`

Comment: in this line `CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, yourArrayList);`

Comment: Does your MainActivity class extend `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`?

Comment: its AppCompatActivity

Comment: Try to change `this` with `getApplicationContext()`. Does it work now?

Comment: `CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),uploadList);`  where uploadList  is `List<Upload> uploadList = new ArrayList<>();`  Error is `Error:(105, 91) error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to Activity`

Comment: I understand nou. Change `Activity` to `Context` as in my updated answer.

Comment: I made the change here: `CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Upload> arrayList) {` and you can use also `this` insted of `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads);
```

when initializing the adapter, you will only get one text there, example the `name` (Dil Diyan Gallar) in your database.

This part here:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

means only one `textview` in each item, so there is no subitems. If you want to have more than one `textview` either use a custom adapter or use `simple_list_item_2` and change your code accordingly.